# pickle object with overloaded __new__

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, pickle

In my program I'm using class derived from class of immutable objects (namedtuple). I've chosen to do so, because tuples seemed to result in significantly smaller sizes of files on disk (I didn't check their loadability at first.) Also, there are several static constant object in use. Depending on input `__new__` can abort the calculation and return one of the static objects instead.

I've overrided the `__new__` method. The `__new__` takes less arguments than there are fields and does non-trivial computations to obtain other fields' values. When I try to unpickle the objects of the class, the `__new__` method gets called in a way it should not. The example below is stripped version of the problem.

Example:

```
import pickle

class testclass(tuple):
     def __new__(cls,x):
         assert type(x)==int, "Wrong input type to constructor"
         return super().__new__(cls,[x,x*2,x**2])

pickle.loads(pickle.dumps( testclass(4),protocol = -1))
```

Output:

> AssertionError

How do I create tuple objects with custom constructor, that are also serializable?

---

Extended example. The initial calculations are time consuming and unreversible:

```
import pickle, time

class testclass(tuple):
     def __new__(cls,params):
         assert type(params)==dict, "Wrong input type to constructor"
         a = params['sec']
         p,g = 23, 5
         r = p**a % g
         time.sleep(params['wait'])
         return super().__new__(cls,[p,g,r])

pickle.loads(pickle.dumps( testclass({'sec':4,'wait':1}),protocol = -1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by defining a [`__getnewargs__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__) method for `pickle` to use:

```
import pickle


class Testclass(tuple):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        assert isinstance(x, int), "Wrong input type to constructor"
        return super().__new__(cls, (x, x*2, x**2))

    def __getnewargs__(self):
        return (self[0],)  # Just return first element of sequence.


pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(Testclass(4), protocol=-1))
```

Comment: Right, this only works because of particular simplicity of the minimal example. What if `self[0]` was not equal to the input?

Comment: @Dimitry: In that case I suggest your minimal example is too much so. Please edit your question and provide something that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the end, the answer I've settled with was "not to pickle object with overloaded `__new__`".

```
import pickle, time
class Testclass(tuple):
     @classmethod 
     def new(cls,params):
         a = params['sec']
         p,g = 23, 5
         r = p**a % g
         time.sleep(params['wait'])
         return cls([p,g,r])

pickle.loads(pickle.dumps( Testclass.new({'sec':4,'wait':1}),protocol = -1))
```

In my code, I could replace all calls to constructor with explicit function calls. The creation\unpickling then was left to default constructors that don't do much beyond setting the fields.